# Strange syntax in package.json file of a vscode extenson

Tags: python, node.js, visual-studio-code, package.json, vscode-extensions

I'm reading the code of [vscode-python](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python). When I read [package.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/package.json) I see some strange syntax, ex: `"title": "%python.command.python.refactorExtractVariable.title%",`. I did some research but I cannot find a glue. Can you tell me some or can you explain me about this syntax?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is for localization. Depending on the selected locale of the system, the title of each command/menu item will be displayed in that language. The mapping of this variable to the actual label in a given language is mentioned in a separate file. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/package.nls.ja.json) is the file for the Japanese language. Line 10 shows the command you mentioned in Japanese characters as:

`"python.command.python.refactorExtractVariable.title": "変数を抽出",`

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/i18n-sample) is an example extension that explains how to use `%some.key%` syntax.